# Fetch data from JSON with key id with sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I would like to show some data from my api,

```
{#each Object.values(product.options.???) as value}
        <div">
            {value.name}
        </div>
    {/each}
```

This is the result of product.options
[image]

I would like to show values => [0] or [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2VNo.png), but i don't know what i have to add, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to use of `Object.values` in this case.

You can use an `each` for the options, like:

```
{#each product.options as value}
```

And then use one for the values, like:

```
{#each value.values as option}
```

So it can look like this:

```
{#each product.options as value}
    <div>
        {value.name}
        <ul>
            {#each value.values as option}
              <li>{option}</li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
    </div>
{/each}
```

([Working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/b6be453f9dd947e6ae2ef1418d683b24?version=3.45.0))